# System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125))

Tags: apex, webservices, json, rest, parser

I am passing the below JSON structure using POST method to a apex service:

I get an error at line where the `codes` variable ends

```
{
"PId" : "345",
"Description" : "test",
"Codes" :[
    {
    "Code" : " ",
    "qw" : " ",
    "qwe" : " ",
    "Desc" : " ",
    "RT": " ",
    } ], <- Error at this line 
"AccountName" : "Account 001",
"AccountNumber" : "123333" ,
"Address" : "NY",
}
```

Error:

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was
>   expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:14, column:3]

Am I forming the JSON correctly ?

Comment: Is it not the extra comma you have at line 14? Also, line 10 seems to be the same. Strongly suggest you use this [JS code quality tool](http://jshint.com/) for these niggly errors.

Comment: Does this tool correct the JSON Structucture?

Comment: Lets not get carried away... It will clearly state the formatting errors line by line, unlike SF error reporting. An alternative, [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) will highlight the errors and provide hints and tips. Cool tool too.

Comment: @TSmith jshint is not appropriate here. JSON is more strict than JavaScript. Trailing commas are allowed in JavaScript, but not in JSON. A more appropriate tool would be [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing "," is not allowed. The final element in an object or array must not have a comma after it.

```
{
"PId" : "345",
"Description" : "test",
"Codes" :[
    {
    "Code" : " ",
    "qw" : " ",
    "qwe" : " ",
    "Desc" : " ",
    "RT": " "
    } ],
"AccountName" : "Account 001",
"AccountNumber" : "123333" ,
"Address" : "NY"
}
```